# c# - how to make this code as different manner?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Below code is my interview question but I don't know how to make perfect

Code:

```
    public class Shape
    {
        public void Rectangle(int length, int height)
        { 
            Console.Write(length * height);
        }

        public void Circle(int radius)
        {
            Console.Write(3.14 * (radius * radius));
        }
    }
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Comment: 1. Where is the actual question? You only show your answer. 2. "perfect" in which sense?

Comment: what do you mean better..? please share the interview question if u want help

Comment: The first thing IMO is naming - I wouldn't expect Circle(3) to print something or calculate its area, but rather to create an object. Also just printing is a strange choice as it is not universal (maybe you want to execute it in browser, maybe in GUI) - function should return value, not just print. Pi is a constant and you should use an exact constant value rather than typing it in. I don't get even started on the whole design choice as I'm no expert myself, but the structure seems way off from being easily extendable and reusable.

Comment: what do you mean perfecT? there is no actual QUESTION!

Comment: I guess interviewer wanted you to write classes and implement calculateArea for them.

Comment: And why length, height and radius are ints?

Comment: @Adarsh You are most likely right. I think this was question about OOP really and there should be classes Rectangle and Circle derived from Shape and .area() function implemented.

Comment: How to apply OOPS in this code?

Comment: Seriously, @user2500094, read through basic inheritance examples. This shape exercise is a classical thing which you can find in multiple books. (I remember it from Thinking in Java) Sorry, but this site is not for tutoring and this question is basically asking to guide you through basics of OOP.

Comment: [How to: Define Abstract Properties (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd3z1377.aspx)

Comment: Here you go, @Damith has answered your question :)

Answer (score 4):

How about?

```
public abstract class Shape
{
    public abstract int CalcArea();
}

public class Rectangle : Shape
{
    public int Height { get; set; }
    public int Width { get; set; }

    public override int CalcArea()
    {
        return Height * Width;
    }
}

public class Circle : Shape
{
    public float Radius { get; set; }

    public override int CalcArea()
    {
        return Math.PI * (Radius * Radius);
    }
}
```

Comment: it's confusing that the method called `CalcArea()` actually *prints* the area. It would be better to name the method `PrintArea()` instead. Or even better: not rename method and *return* the calculated area instead of printing it.

Answer (score 0):

- Make `Shape` an interface or abstract class
- Declare an abstract method `getArea()` in `Shape`
- Make `Rectangle` and `Circle` subclasses of `Shape`, `Rectangle` having height and width, `Circle` having radius.
- Implement `getArea()` in `Rectangle` and `Circle` (returning h*w in `Rectangle` and π*r<sup>2</sup> in `Circle`)